# iOS - How to have UITableView with edit mode exactly like Contacts App?

Tags: ios, uitableview, contacts, edit

I am building an app that will have it's own list of 'contacts'. It will not be connected to the device's actual contacts app.

However, I want to basically imitate the Contacts app 100%.

That is, have a table view to display user info (done!) and allow a user to edit the user info and have the table view "animate" into a slightly altered table (just like the Contacts App does!).

How does the Contacts app work when it comes to the "transformation" of the table when going into edit mode?

Answer (score 1):

It is all in the [UITableView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableView):

> When sent a `setEditing:animated:` message (with a first parameter of
>   `YES`), the table view enters into editing mode where it shows the
>   editing or reordering controls of each visible row, depending on the
>   editingStyle of each associated `UITableViewCell`. Clicking on the
>   insertion or deletion control causes the data source to receive a
>   `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` message. You commit a
>   deletion or insertion by calling
>   `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` or
>   `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`, as appropriate. Also in
>   editing mode, if a table-view cell has its `showsReorderControl`
>   property set to `YES`, the data source receives a
>   `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` message. The data source can
>   selectively remove the reordering control for cells by implementing
>   `tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:`

You also use the [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate) methods to set up how rows appear in editing mode

`– tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:`
`– tableView:titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:`
`– tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:`

And these methods from the [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource):

**Inserting or Deleting Table Rows**
`– tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`
`– tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:`

If there is something specific you are not sure about please ask something specific.